# Merge 2 vanilla javascript files into one file with Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a HTML + vanillaJS project that works fine. It looks like this:

index.html

```html
...
<script src="foo_class.js"></script>
<script src="main.js"></script>
...
```

foo_class.js

```js
class Foo { ... }
```

main.js

```js
new Foo();
```

Since I want to use Typescript, I changed the `.js` extensions to `.ts`. Next I would like to:

- Replace the 2 `<script>` tags in the HTML by just one `<script src="all_code.js"></script>`
- Tell TypeScript that the 2 JavaScript files need each other to work (by using `import/export` or something similar)

I tried many combinations of `import/export` and `tsconfig.json` (with the `outFile` option), but nothing seems to work. I either get errors when doing `tsc` or when opening the `index.html` file in my browser.

Comment: What combinations? What errors? Give a [mre].

Comment: not so fast, browsers can not run TypeScript natively, you have to transpile it first